# Android: What is best practice for declaring View components in an Activity?

Tags: android, design-patterns, view, components, declare

A typical activity in android.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /* Should I declare view components here? */
    TextView textView;
    Button button;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      /* And then create them here */
      textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview); 
      button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);       
      recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);   

      /* Or is it better to declare and create them like this? */
      Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);    
    }
}
```

In both cases, the components will work as intended and can be used as intended. However, is there a programming practice or pattern one should follow when declaring views like that in your main activity or fragments? Or does it simply not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you write. I'll say a **summary** about that.

1. If you declare the views outside onCreate, you will be able to use these views in any method in your activity/fragment.
2. But if you declare the view in a method like onCreate, you won't be able to reference these views again at all in any other different method. It can only be referenced in that same method you wrote your view declaration in.

However, from my coding experience, I always like to declare them outside onCreate. It has more accessibility, and you won't lose anything.

Answer (score 1):

It depends!

If you need to access view components outside `onCreate`, in other methods of the class, which are not called from the `onCreate`, then, you can choose to store references to such view components as instance variables.  This is true for things likes text views, list views, etc. which may have to be updated from other methods of the class.

If you do not need view components outside `onCreate`, then, there is no need to make them instance variables.  This is true typically for buttons, where once you define the `setOnClickListener`, you may not need to access that component again.

Few developers prefer to declare instance variables for all the view components.  Some even declare them as `static` variables, and access them from other classes - and even misuse it share data between activities. In a multi-member teams, this conventions is hard to maintain - some variables gets declared as member variables, and some gets missed out.  Many times, some of the member variables are never accessed outside `onCreate` and adds to clutter in code.

Answer (score 0):

Thumb-rule, declare in class if you want to use in other function(s)